# DHIS-2 not running

Tags: java, maven, dhis-2

I want to use DHIS-2 in my local system (localhost). i follow steps from [here](https://www.dhis2.org/development). And all files build in my system by following command

```
mvn install // on dhis-2 Dir and also /dhis-2/dhis-web
```

But i can't get this command work `mvn jetty:run-war`  every time it give error.

Is there any step by step solution fro my problem?
I want to run DHIS-2 in my local system using Eclipse.
I am completely lost and want some guidelines.

Comment: Were  you able to import the project into eclipse? I am have issue importing it into eclipse [my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29958806/dhis2-eclipse-import-issue-using-bazaar)

Comment: i got its build file (war file) using cmd commands and then deploy to server.

Answer (score 4):

First navigate to `dhis-2/dhis-web/dhis-web-portal` and then run:

```
mvn jetty:run-war
```

You might get this exception:

```
Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "main"
```

If you do, edit your `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` and add:

```
export _JAVA_OPTIONS="-Xmx7500m -Xms4000m -XX:MaxPermSize=500m -XX:PermSize=300m"
```

Answer (score 1):

All web modules in DHIS 2 can be started as stand-alone web applications. With web modules I mean all Maven projects under dhis-2/dhis-web/. The modules under dhis-2/ are referred to as service modules. First build the service modules with "mvn install" like you have done. Then navigate to any of the web modules, e.g.:

```
cd dhis-2/dhis-web/dhis-web-reporting
```

From there you can execute the jetty plugin with:

```
mvn jetty:run
```

Notice that you should not use -war flag anymore.