# DHIS2 - Eclipse Import Issue using Bazaar

Tags: eclipse, bazaar, bazaar-plugins, dhis-2

After download the project using,

```
bzr branch lp:~dhis2-devs-core/dhis2/2.18
```

I am getting the following error when trying to import DHIS2 project using Bazaar into Eclipse EE Luna Version 4.4.2:

> [Error 206] The filename or extension is too long: u
>        'D:/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.vcs.bazaar.eclipse.core/bzreclipse5417078662519156113.tmp/.bzr/checkout/limbo/new-2/dhis-web/dhis-web-commons-resources/src/main/webapp/dhis-web-commons/javascripts/ext/resources/themes/images/gray/form-invalid-tip'

Answer (score 1):

Try installing the m2e plugin which provides maven integration for eclipse:

http://www.eclipse.org/m2e/

After installing, you can go to File > Import > Existing Maven project. Click Next, locate the root folder of your checkout and click Import.

Comment: Thanks @lars, I have already done that, but still the same. Later, tried to import the (downloaded via bazaar) project as "Existing Maven Projects", project was imported but it had many errors, some related to dependency and for other I looks like the project was note imported appropriately.